# Favorite bracket for your favorite mics

Tags: microphone, gear, field-recording, techniques

Who has a favorite bracket for a pair of condensers they'd like to recommend? I'm thinking about either Oktavas or Earthworks, and would like the flexibility of recording in X-Y, ORTF and spaced pair in the field. Zeppelins and Rycote fuzzies would be good to accommodate, as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow. I'm surprised this post has gone so long unanswered.

Here's my two cents:

http://www.schoeps.de/en/products/ums20

http://www.schoeps.de/en/products/stc

But I absolutely love M/S recording with a CMIT 5U and a CCM 8 on a KMSC double clip. You can see this configuration in the user manual of the CMIT 5U. It's awesome.

Just gotta make sure all the slits of the tube on the shotgun are not covered and that the capsules are lined up (it's at the bottom of the interference tube, not at the tip like some people think it is) exactly and it gives very good results.

- Ryan

Comment: Thanks for answering my poor, forlorn question. In return, you are awarded the Best Answer checkmark!